# error if "else" begins with a new php block

Tags: php

Just curious to know why the code below gives "unexpected T_ELSE" syntax error:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) { ?>
            <h2>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION["user_id"]; ?></h2>
<?php } ?>
<?php else { ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="user">User ID</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

While I keep the } else { on same line, it works fine. I mean the code below just works fine:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) { ?>
            <h2>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION["user_id"]; ?></h2>
<?php } else { ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="user">User ID</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: there is no strange  behavior from php ,in one php block if block started and closed so its not looking for else part ...

Comment: It would appear to be a limitation or bug in the PHP parser. What version? Presumably, if it were to keep the possibility of ELSE open for longer it would need to scan the entire source-file before being able to output anything. Good find, but probably not a biggie.

Comment: reproducable with PHP 5.3.10

Comment: i am able to reproduce your error, unfortunately i can't locate any reference to this issue. Hope someone can answer this.

Comment: My server runs on PHP 5.2.17

Comment: If anyone files a bug report, please link to it in this question, so there aren't any duplicate reports floating around.

Comment: you should update your server ASAP! ;) - interesting find, though...never thought about it, but it makes sense considering the explanations in the answers

Comment: Posted a Bug report https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65232 see what we hear back.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan It's a gray area, but I would have to agree.  Maybe just some additional documentation is needed (which would also be submitted as a *bug* report), even if it's not a bug.

Comment: This is not a bug, rather PHP parser treats every code block separately. I understood from the comments that a else statement in a new PHP code block doen't know of a if statement of previous code block. Thanks for knowing me this! Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thinking a bit about this, I've come to the realization that this has to be the intended behavior.

consider the following (syntactical **wrong** ) example:

```
<?php if ($condition == true) { ?>
  <div id="first">Yey</div>
<?php } ?>
<span id="second?">where am I?</span>
<?php else { ?>
  <div id="first">Ney</div>
<?php } ?>
```

the span element would be in an undefined state

Comment: I think this is the best explanation I've seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing weird per se, it's because you're in a separate code block, that's the simplest way to put it. Nothing is open at the time of you "Leaving PHP", so when you go back into it there is no context.

Consider your code like this (of course consider it as pseudo-code just to emphasise the point):

```
if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    // ....
}; else {
    // ....
}
```

Breaking in/out of PHP can be tricky at times, and managing it like you want to in your first example doesn't really make very much sense.

You might want to consider using this, which would put your transition to the `else` block on a single line anyway:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])): ?>
    <h2>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION["user_id"]; ?></h2>
<?php else: ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="user">User ID</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
<?php endif ?>
```

At the end of the day whilst PHP is pretty flexible I wouldn't expect it to allow you to do what you're wanting. That would allow for an `else` block to be added miles away which may not be the intention at all.

Comment: »Nothing is open at the time of you "Leaving PHP"« Mmh, but a single block stays "open": `<?php if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) { ?> Outside PHP Code, but inside a PHP block. <?php } ?>`

Comment: What? That's exactly what I said. When he closes it (`} ?>`) the block is no longer open. The next time a code block is open there is no context of the previous `if` as it is considered "done".

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that you can't start a new code block with an `else` statement without a preceding `if`.

You could…

A) write your code in one block, e.g.

```
<?php }
else { ?>
```

B) or [use the alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), if you are working with multiple code-blocks:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])): ?>
    /* … */
<?php else: ?>
    /* … */
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php } ?>
        ^^
```

> When PHP parses a file, it looks for opening and closing tags, which are  which tell PHP to start and stop interpreting the code between them. Parsing in this manner allows PHP to be embedded in all sorts of different documents, as everything outside of a pair of opening and closing tags is ignored by the PHP parser.

When the PHP parser comes to this line it executes the if block only. After that PHP parser tried to parse the next block of code(**else part**) but here it start with `else {` and because of that `else` is separated from `if` and produces error.

Comment: @STTLCU I read it carefully. Just too lazy to include more info. :)

Comment: @STTLCU I would like to hear your opinion ..please post.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar While it makes sense how the parser decides to stop searching for an `else` statement after encountering a close tag, your quote does not support your statements.  It does not specify why a syntax error is not encountered once a close tag is encountered if there is a `<?php } else { ?>` later on (i.e. syntax error for no closing brace).